# Extend WP_User_Query or WP_User to return all custom fields?

Tags: custom-field, users, user-meta, wp-user-query

I'm trying to pull out list of about 5000+ member records for CSV export. The query is timed out and I suppose the reason is that in order to populate the CSV file I need to iterate over those 5000 records and pull custom meta for each user separately.

Is it possible to extend or override either WP_User_Query or WP_User to return all custom meta in single query?

Basically what I need to do is to get rid of calling get_user_meta($user->ID) for each record individually and get all meta in one result set.

Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this its better off (IHMO) to simple use a custom query using the [`$wpdb class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

ex:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

//first get a list of all meta keys
$keys = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT distinct meta_key FROM $wpdb->usermeta");

//then prepare the meta keys query as fields which we'll join to the user table fields
$meta_columns = '';
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $meta_columns .= " MAX(CASE WHEN um1.meta_key = '$key' THEN um1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS ".str_replace('-','_',$key).", \n";
}

//then write the main query with all of the regular fields and use a simple left join on user users.ID and usermeta.user_id
$query = "
SELECT  
    u.ID,
    u.user_login,
    u.user_pass,
    u.user_nicename,
    u.user_email,
    u.user_url,
    u.user_registered,
    u.user_activation_key,
    u.user_status,
    u.display_name,
    ".rtrim($meta_columns,", \n") ." 
FROM 
    $wpdb->users u
LEFT JOIN 
    $wpdb->usermeta um1 ON (um1.user_id = u.ID)
GROUP BY 
    u.ID";

$users  = $wpdb->get_results($query,ARRAY_A);
var_dump($users);
```

keep in mind that this is an example you hould build on like filtering unwanted users and meta keys.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was affraid that I won't be able to do it with the WP_User_Query:( See the problem is that I already have pretty robust filtering system that uses WP_User_Query along with pre_user_query hook, as the CSV should be generated based on dynamic criteria. But it seems that I'll have to redo the whole thing:)

Comment: Not really, You can change your `WP_User_Query` to return just the user ID's and filter the above example based on these IDS using the WHERE clause. something like `WHERE u.ID in (//ids go here comma seperated)`

Comment: I see, so it would be two queries. 1st using WP_User_Query and then the 2nd query would be using WP_User_Query output as source for WPDB call. Right? I think that should do the trick:) Thanks for your help:)

Comment: Yet that sounds about right but its ok since the first query is just getting the ids it should be a light query and if you think about it you are saving all of the get_user_meta Queries.